# iPhone app crash on iOS 4.0

Tags: iphone, crash, ios4

All crash reports submitted for our application on iOS 4.0 are giving the below information:

```
Application Specific Information:
<my app name>[3532] was suspended with locked system files:
/private/var/mobile/Library/AddressBook/AddressBook.sqlitedb
```

Any idea what this indicates and what could be the possible cause of crash. Our application is not interacting with AddressBook.sqlitedb at all.

The complete crash log:

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0xdead10cc
Highlighted Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
app name[3532] was suspended with locked system files: 
/private/var/mobile/Library/AddressBook/AddressBook.sqlitedb

Thread 0:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3302e4ac object_dispose
1   CoreFoundation                  0x31372cfe -[NSObject(NSObject) dealloc]
2   QuartzCore                      0x33e45264 -[CALayer dealloc]
3   QuartzCore                      0x33eb5e60 -[CALayer _dealloc]
4   QuartzCore                      0x33e3c752 CALayerRelease
5   QuartzCore                      0x33e3cd20 CA::release_root_if_unused(_CALayer*, _CALayer*, void*)
6   QuartzCore                      0x33e3ccbc x_hash_table_remove_if
7   QuartzCore                      0x33e3cb26 CA::Transaction::commit()
8   QuartzCore                      0x33e42406 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x313caa42 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
10  CoreFoundation                  0x313cc46e __CFRunLoopDoObservers
11  CoreFoundation                  0x313cd774 __CFRunLoopRun
12  CoreFoundation                  0x313768e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
13  CoreFoundation                  0x313767ec CFRunLoopRunInMode
14  GraphicsServices                0x329f36e8 GSEventRunModal
15  GraphicsServices                0x329f3794 GSEventRun
16  UIKit                           0x316692a0 -[UIApplication _run]
17  UIKit                           0x31667e10 UIApplicationMain
18  app name                        0x00002a64 main + 36
19  app name                        0x00002a34 start + 32

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35228c4c kevent + 24
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x352d1e44 _dispatch_mgr_invoke
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x352d1894 _dispatch_queue_invoke
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x352d1a34 _dispatch_worker_thread2
4   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35275d82 _pthread_wqthread
5   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3526efcc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x351fc6b4 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35229d92 semaphore_wait_signal
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x351fe4a4 pthread_mutex_lock
3   WebCore                         0x30138194 _WebTryThreadLock(bool)
4   WebCore                         0x301380da WebRunLoopLock(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x313caa42 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
6   CoreFoundation                  0x313cc46e __CFRunLoopDoObservers
7   CoreFoundation                  0x313cd780 __CFRunLoopRun
8   CoreFoundation                  0x313768e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
9   CoreFoundation                  0x313767ec CFRunLoopRunInMode
10  WebCore                         0x30138056 RunWebThread(void*)
11  libSystem.B.dylib               0x35275986 _pthread_start
12  libSystem.B.dylib               0x3526b0e4 thread_start + 0

Thread 3:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x351fc658 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x351fe724 mach_msg
2   CoreFoundation                  0x313cb2c8 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort
3   CoreFoundation                  0x313cd582 __CFRunLoopRun
4   CoreFoundation                  0x313768e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
5   CoreFoundation                  0x313767ec CFRunLoopRunInMode
6   Foundation                      0x3329571e +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:]
7   Foundation                      0x33265c96 -[NSThread main]
8   Foundation                      0x332ea9da __NSThread__main__
9   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35275986 _pthread_start
10  libSystem.B.dylib               0x3526b0e4 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35220a20 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x313d0e70 __CFSocketManager
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35275986 _pthread_start
3   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3526b0e4 thread_start + 0

Thread 5:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3527685c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35275e98 _pthread_wqthread
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3526efcc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3527685c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35275e98 _pthread_wqthread
2   libSystem.B.dylib               0x3526efcc start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libSystem.B.dylib               0x35205974 access + 8
1   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3282f5a6 unixAccess
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x32826e5a sqlite3OsAccess
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x32835bf0 sqlite3BtreeBeginTrans
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3284f038 sqlite3Step
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x3282639c sqlite3_step
6   AppSupport                      0x31475634 CPSqliteStatementCopyStringResult
7   AppSupport                      0x3147626e CPSqliteConnectionCopyValueForProperty
8   AppSupport                      0x314773a2 CPSqliteDatabaseCopyValueForProperty
9   AppSupport                      0x314773ba CPSqliteDatabaseCopyUniqueIdentifier
10  AddressBook                     0x34dd7c3a ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectoryAndForceInProcessMigrationAndResetSortKeys
11  AddressBook                     0x34dd7eba ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectoryAndForceInProcessMigration
12  AddressBook                     0x34dd7ec8 ABCCreateAddressBookWithDatabaseDirectory
13  AddressBook                     0x34de3e78 ABAddressBookCreate
14  TextInput                       0x34973fb8 KB::matchable_strings_from_address_book()
15  TextInput                       0x34978686 KB::DynamicDictionaryImpl::background_load_address_book(KB::StaticDictionary const&)
16  TextInput                       0x34979d36 KB::BackgroundLoad(void*)
17  libSystem.B.dylib               0x35275986 _pthread_start
18  libSystem.B.dylib               0x3526b0e4 thread_start + 0

Unknown thread crashed with unknown flavor: 5, state_count: 1

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x41fff +CVCrDVR armv6  <4ca92ed88199f56c60997ff21ed9963e> /var/mobile/Applications/6EF0091E-FE47-43B7-8515-08688A530869/CVCrDVR.app/CVCrDVR
   0xeb000 -    0xecfff  dns.so armv7  <240b8d3f07b4fcb234de598f8e67de1a> /usr/lib/info/dns.so
   0xf0000 -    0xf4fff  AccessibilitySettingsLoader armv7  <9e7d0552cedc18ba0b26cd182c47df8d> /System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader
0x2fe00000 - 0x2fe26fff  dyld armv7  <193570c1391880df7da870149117e49e> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30135000 - 0x30686fff  WebCore armv7  <859bdd351085819fb4da07d12b41543f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x30ac5000 - 0x30adafff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <1ed920d5a995cd94e71c41631d7c551e> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x30adc000 - 0x30bc4fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <9bcf5fe3e7abc344425e581ff2896579> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
0x30ca5000 - 0x30d4bfff  WebKit armv7  <a1d04572b3214188f60f2d1961ac1fe8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x30eb4000 - 0x30f76fff  CFNetwork armv7  <9fdd61632fd1b48d65daba561528946f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x31297000 - 0x3129cfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <d33678689445fcf1898314262fd1ebd3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3129f000 - 0x312e7fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <3b4a2849c10d100a178a3c2d9f6af523> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x312ea000 - 0x31358fff  ProofReader armv7  <479bd40ac65cb7e6c3000d79d649571f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x31359000 - 0x3142bfff  CoreFoundation armv7  <17c9c36ae8824496b507446869cd4d9d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x31472000 - 0x314a0fff  AppSupport armv7  <2a64271b39599b2180d0dfd3141027ee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x31663000 - 0x3280dfff  UIKit armv7  <6c767127e477e6ac7b7f083857ca8064> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32824000 - 0x32868fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <36b9bc7d02e29c8d321dd0d7bf7e115e> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3286b000 - 0x3286dfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <1fdf9182a63464743901526caf39240a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x329b6000 - 0x329ccfff  RawCamera armv7  <78168f60a21e67ce307c5ce30054dba6> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x329dc000 - 0x329e2fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <df3c6cea5e6848109a6e033e1d883320> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x329e3000 - 0x329ebfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <b8fc1381e87a55740d9ac66195039a63> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x329f0000 - 0x329fbfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <7194df9e594ae0fd9d9c600ccf456a08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x329fc000 - 0x32a46fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <baab09769f92decea73680bc15aa8618> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x32ad3000 - 0x32ad5fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <06dd6032c40b1feb094d63eeb2002d6d> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x32b17000 - 0x32b59fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <bc8796c8e011fea9923170d3c948a694> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32b98000 - 0x32b9bfff  IOSurface armv7  <e67242f81fd1c0fa5e84b3fae5d310ae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x32bb6000 - 0x32bb6fff  vecLib armv7  <85f89752df7814c1b243c26f59388523> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x32bd1000 - 0x32bdbfff  ExternalAccessory armv7  <56a0856978d36be40c42834de8ab966d> /System/Library/Frameworks/ExternalAccessory.framework/ExternalAccessory
0x32de8000 - 0x32f06fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <4022bbf12f11dd1f6b75662c764e7f7c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x32f20000 - 0x32f2dfff  DataDetectorsUI armv7  <8f6e03c382591e1f30f06e97b4b31570> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsUI.framework/DataDetectorsUI
0x3302b000 - 0x330cbfff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <89553a61e05078fd178ac0ea2081ae40> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x3325a000 - 0x33379fff  Foundation armv7  <c985a61696030b4d1bdc8fe010f4e43b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3337c000 - 0x3338efff  VoiceServices armv7  <f5b5b032e4c0b79c42e0fde5a59a6eb3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
0x3344f000 - 0x33489fff  IOKit armv7  <5e0169de165c2fd25a2ddac1f3e19d06> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x33641000 - 0x33680fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b96f5e231a3e39677b5e3621d61d2f11> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x33681000 - 0x33683fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <74e2bd725da63513053b4fa41d8cd89c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3368e000 - 0x3371bfff  ImageIO armv7  <abf07fc0430aaf2a2823753c78061aac> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33850000 - 0x33969fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <c4f4fd74dfa672fb4d84914585bbada5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x33c6f000 - 0x33c87fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <436e3b257ba088ca6f773961ce619892> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x33c88000 - 0x33c8bfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <12f82e44ff36b29f8d0661878be83554> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33c90000 - 0x33c9cfff  DataDetectorsCore armv7  <bc6bff5b67aae8b97a8cdd43ed7b0bb1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/DataDetectorsCore
0x33e36000 - 0x33edefff  QuartzCore armv7  <109b4f6a3d2ee5aa1bb5775ab5a489bc> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x33ee2000 - 0x33f8bfff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <1d74fa3a5cec309857503a51cb2df667> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x34035000 - 0x342cffff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <fbc3f7ad1260a159d75be53218fa9e0c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x343a8000 - 0x343b1fff  CoreVideo armv7  <58180e899ec56cd8bca00221dea2bc32> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x343ee000 - 0x3442cfff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <cc8d6be7a5021266e26ebd05e9579852> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x3442d000 - 0x34435fff  libkxld.dylib armv7  <4ec35c4d1e1e73416aea84537829ce91> /usr/lib/system/libkxld.dylib
0x34438000 - 0x34445fff  OpenGLES armv7  <e397de408a0a789f816bc1803ae58faf> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x344e8000 - 0x34521fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <d38c937ae3548777da263d2657536189> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3456c000 - 0x3459bfff  CoreText armv7  <76eb1b63d684c3d21dba9e8129666d2f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x3459c000 - 0x345d2fff  Security armv7  <7cea1027f1a381b8d6c5ffae4dae0d22> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x3473c000 - 0x347dbfff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <894df23ebbc4df713d9519141a61dd19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x347dc000 - 0x347ddfff  CoreSurface armv7  <042e433142b7faa4c96b23e555faaf13> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x34844000 - 0x3484bfff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <5d079712f5a39708647292bccbd4c4e0> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3487c000 - 0x348aafff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <2b44ac2fc47fc45c4006d08019688dbb> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x348ac000 - 0x348b7fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <19a78978d5908bedc6496470fe542936> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x348e9000 - 0x34929fff  CoreAudio armv7  <1723726845b73efbeca75b33d75f335a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3493e000 - 0x3496cfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <475259824770c6ff1b63f30238b3ea81> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x3496d000 - 0x349a3fff  TextInput armv7  <949f29588014140b606042685de1dee6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x349a4000 - 0x349c3fff  Bom armv7  <c73b68b11b2801cefbfbdb6328a7fcfb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x34dd5000 - 0x34e07fff  AddressBook armv7  <3dde743216bbf016019b59f821dda6e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x34f43000 - 0x34f4ffff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <7624f0a9e197261f2df43edb86ba0256> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x34f50000 - 0x34f5dfff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <27ad6b3a74ce1068586eabd6a553183f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34f5e000 - 0x34f64fff  IAP armv7  <42a87fc47e059f5a73dcff2227b9e0be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x3502d000 - 0x35151fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <802e4d5c449b69d9552809e5230baa84> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x35156000 - 0x35156fff  Accelerate armv7  <f4c04cdfdb64d209828315cdd5b60bf9> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x351fb000 - 0x35308fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <3fcf32f3ad8ef745480b5b36efc41953> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

We tried symbolicatecrash too, but it doesn't point to anywhere.

Thanks and Regards,
Hetal

Comment: Can you provide more of the stacktrace/call stack?

Comment: I have added the crash log info to the question. Please have a look at let me know if you can deduce anything from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using any kind of file ?
it seems like you trying to access locked files..

Read this from [Apple Developer Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html)

Determining the Availability of Protected Files
A protected file can be accessed only when a device is unlocked. Because applications may continue running while a device is locked, your code should be prepared to handle the possibility of protected files becoming unavailable at any time. The UIKit framework provides ways to track whether data protection is currently enabled.

Comment: We are saving some images to documents directory after downloading them over the net and using those. Apart from it, we are saving and retrieving data from NSUserDefaults. Apart from that, we have no other file access. I am including more stack trace in the question. Please have a look and let me know if that helps deduce something.

Comment: I kind of remember having same kind of error.... again not sure it was exact same... but it was coming bcoz I just had read permission on the file... so you might wanna try checking permissions for the files and folders.

Comment: Having the same issue. What's strange though, I'm never writing to ABAddressBook (except through ABAddressBookUI which does its own thing). Also, there's just the `ABAddressBookCreate()` call and nothing to close it (without saving) explicitly. Did I miss something?

Comment: I have the same error and I also do this: We are saving some images to documents directory after downloading them over the net and using those.

Answer (score 3):

The crash log indicates that your application was still accessing the AddressBook when your app suspended. Your app needs to `CFRelease` its access to the AddressBook in your
`applicationDidEnterBackground:` delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Pat and Roi, if you look through your stack trace you will find that you are using the address book, in thread 5 and 7 respectively.  Perhaps you are using an API that accesses the address book?
We have this problem, and are looking for a way to message the background thread that is accessing the address book when the app is backgrounded.  Will update this thread when we find it.